# Wordpress looks for the php files in the wrong place (after redirected)

Tags: wordpress

Our Wordpress is installed on blog.survio.cz with defined WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://blog.survio.cz');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://blog.survio.cz');
```

However for SEO purposes we redirect it (with 301 redirect) to http://www.survio.com/cs/blog/

The trouble I'm facing is that this redirect screws a lot with Wordpress functionality.

The latest problem is that I can't add comments.
F.e.: in the post http://www.survio.com/cs/blog/novinky/jak-zvysit-pocet-vyplnenych-dotazniku when I scroll down and fill in comment and hit submit (odeslat komentar), I see blank page with URL http://www.survio.com/wp-comments-post.php - the URL is obviously wrong.

My question is: is there a way for me to change, where the wordpress looks for this .php? (It is probably located at blog.survio.cz/wp-comments-post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**
The problem is that when the comment form is generated Wordpress is setting the action with a relative URL.

```
<form action="/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form anti-spam-form-processed" novalidate="">
```

The browser then fills in that url with `http://www.survio.com/` since it doesn't know anything about `blog.survio.cz`.  And, of course, http://www.survio.com/wp-comments-post.php doesn't exist.

So, what you need to do is to change it so that the action attribute gets set with an absolute url.  But how?

It turns out that in Wordpress core, the code that generates that line of HTML starts like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-comments-post.php' ); ?>"
```

Which means that site_url('/wp-comments-post.php') is returning '/wp-comments-post.php'.  It does that because the site_url function prepends the site_url stored in the WP database before whatever string is passed to it.  So, evidently, the site_url in the database.

**The Fix**

You can probably fix this by setting the site_url to 'http://blog.survio.cz' in your General Options page of your site.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, how the comments work, it helped me to better understand wordpress. It did not however solve the problem as the fix is already applied before the question was asked. We have chosen to fix this problem in removing the redirect and using survio.com/cs/blog as a direct address (without redirecting). Because of all that, the bounty is yours :)

Comment: Thanks!  I anticipated that--after a week--you must have figured out some way through or around the problem.  But I figured the explanation might help others.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must edit your "options" table. In this table you have two record for "WP_HOME" and "WP_SITEURL". Edit this two record with address of your domain.

Comment: Already done (wrote about it in the OP):

define('WP_HOME','http://blog.survio.cz');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://blog.survio.cz');